# Fragmentmanager 2nd variable

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I have an issue with the FragmentManager. I am trying to get a google map in a fragment. This is my fragment. I want to make a map for a given position using com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.1

>

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.spoturdeal.spoturdeal.R;


public class MapShopsFragment extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mapdeals);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Somewhere, and move the camera.
        LatLng somewhere = new LatLng(51, 6);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(somewhere).title("Marker in somewhere"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(somewhere));
    }
}
```

The MainActivity has the following imports

>

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Process;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.Manifest;


import com.spoturdeal.spoturdeal.R;
import com.spoturdeal.spoturdeal.fragments.MapShopsFragment;
```

I have checked that I am using android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity 
The code that has the issue is this part

>

```
private void displayInitialFragment() {

        MapShopsFragment mapShopsFragment = new MapShopsFragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentmanager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentmanager.beginTransaction()
                .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.anim_slide_in_from_left, R.anim.anim_slide_out_from_left)
                .replace(R.id.relativelayout_for_fragment,
                       mapShopsFragment,          /** here is the Problem
                       mapShopsfragment.getTag() 
                ).commit();

    }
```

The error message I can when building is Error:(77, 25) error: incompatible types: MapShopsFragment cannot be converted to Fragment

I have several more fragments that i am working with they have problem. They are extended as ListFragments.

I do not want to make the map in another Activity because I have to set my Material design menu to it.

At the status line of android studio I get the following message

> 'replace(int, android.support.v4.app.Fragment)' in 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction' cannot be applied to '(int, com.spoturdeal.spoturdeal.fragments.MapShopsFragment)' but do not understand what is meant by it.

I was able to get the Fragment working with the help of @ben to get the Map working with play-services:9.2.1 was a bit harder. Below is the solution that worked perfectly.

>

```
public class MapShopsFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {


    private MapView mapView;
    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.mapdeals, container, false);

    }
    public void  onViewCreated(View v, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.map);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mapView.onResume();
        mapView.getMapAsync(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        googleMap = map;
        ......
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your creating a FragmentActivity not a Fragment. Fragment manager expects you to pass a Support Fragment. For what you're doing to work MapShopsFragment needs to extend Fragment.

Comment: Mine MainActivity only want the import > com.spoturdeal.spoturdeal.fragments.MapShopsFragment; if I add import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; it will be in grey

Comment: Hello Ben, thanks for the help so far. I Fragment seems to work. But Now I am nit able to get the mapview properly. I got this error > Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView

Comment: You'd have to paste the code where you are getting the exception. But that means somewhere you are inflating or setting a view as a FrameLayout instead of a map view.

Comment: Hello Ben, thanks for your help. I got the Map part running and my app is working perfectly